# Why stateRoot, transactionsRoot and receiptsRoot not included in the blockheader of any etherscan ?

Tags: ethereum-classic, merkle-patricia-tries

My question may be stupid. I'm trying to understand how ethereum is made and in all articles I read that a block header include a list of things and the stateRoot, the transactionsRoot and the receiptsRoot. However, I cannot see any of these three things in any ether scan (for instance https://etherscan.io/block/5958485).

How is that possible ? Where are the roots of the patricia tree ??
Thank you for your answers ! If you can show me a root, I would warmly thank you !! :)

Comment: What do you mean by “how is that possible”? Why would etherscan have to list the roots?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found this, as I was working on geth :

`web3.eth.getBlock(13, function(e, r) { blockInfo = r; });
undefined
blockInfo
{
  difficulty: 131072,
  extraData: "0xd783010703846765746887676f312e392e31856c696e7578",
  gasLimit: 2126793,
  gasUsed: 21000,
  hash: "0xfb9d5eccda077c720a57343e2c1e6e3298bab1256a35170659e219bba96d0436",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: "0x80b7323d40e36fe32f6838aa92ca5f1367492c57",
  mixHash: "0x7e5161377886b57cf84e58f631e9d13f0e627decbab42422c199234e064385bb",
  nonce: "0x28fd8f84deabdafc",
  number: 13,
  parentHash: "0xc641b8031366b7e3a6cdcd4a674e2b40d76abe9ca581c108f851f16a5e331271",
  receiptsRoot: "0x78ce77b839224d44e0a98f64b943fbe4ffd49e467edb741e8819bf19caacba6d",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 643,
  stateRoot: "0xce5a1bc5be36de30c06eb0245924f2183d0cd27461c36325d53ad9e7c9291b43",
  timestamp: 1532027300,
  totalDifficulty: 1708170,
  transactions: ["0xa95236a540aa01e519e1fb3c0519924a09c9427c2ae3f0c4fec6a46d48d6fe31"],
  transactionsRoot: "0xa74e9ef5f851719122e8d019bdf904b6c9795f953cec28cfea54d7aafa66c50a",
  uncles: []
}`

This is actually all the basic informations included into each block. EtherScan just do not show the receiptsRoot, stateRoot and the transactionRoot. But they are here!

Hope this may help someone trying to dive into Ethereum...